# MapReduce for Loading TSV

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to load data into Cloud Bigtable using mapreduce job such that the values of the first column are set to hbase row key.Here is my code and a sample TSV file.

```
1011    v1  v2  v3  v4
1012    c1  c2  c3  c4
1013    k1  k2  k3  k4
1014    s1  s2  s3  s4
1015    r1  r3  r2  r4
1016    p1  p2  p7  p9
```

Here is my code sample :-

```
    public static class TokenizerMapper extends
            Mapper<Text, Text, Text,Text> {
        @Override
        public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {

            String fields[] = null;
            CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser('\t');
            fields = csvParser.parseLine(value.toString());
            LOG.info(fields[0]);
            context.write(new Text(fields[0]), value);
        }
    }

    public static class MyTableReducer extends
            TableReducer<Text, Text, Text> {
        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String[] fields = null;
            CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser('\t');
            try {
                for(Text value: values) {
                    fields = csvParser.parseLine(value.toString());
                    for (int i = 1; i < fields.length; ++i) {

                        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(fields[0]));
                        put.addColumn(COLUMN_FAMILY, Bytes.toBytes(cols[i]), Bytes.toBytes(fields[i]));
                        context.write(key, put);

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                context.getCounter("HBaseKVMapper", "PARSE_ERRORS").increment(1);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
conf.set("mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator", "\t");
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "BigTableLoader");
        job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
        KeyValueTextInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(args[0]));

        TableName tableName = TableName.valueOf(args[1]);
        job.setJarByClass(BigtableLoader.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        TableMapReduceUtil.initTableReducerJob(tableName.getNameAsString(), MyTableReducer.class, job);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

The problem I am getting is that instead of the first column, the second column has been set as the key in the table, and also the first column is ignored completely i.e. it doesn't exist in the table.
Is there that something I am missing??

Comment: what value you are getting for fields[0] in your mapper?

Comment: There is nothing that is printed even after logging, so I am not aware

Comment: How big is your data file that you are importing? If it's not a large file, it may be faster and easier to import it in a single process, not using MapReduce, since it won't require debugging how CSV records are serialized/passed in MR.

Comment: What does your col array look like?  Do you have an empty value in col[0]?

Comment: @SolomonDuskis the col array is an array of string something like this
String col = {"Atg_id","173","174","175","176"}, these are the names of the column qualifiers that I am using

Comment: Not sure why the first column is ending up in the rowkey, but note that you're mapping fields[1] (what you intend to be the first column) to cols[1] (the second column). This seems incorrect.